# Openlayer4 ClosestPoint() doesn't intersect Feature?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

Hello I'm using Openlayer v4.3.1 and trying the following codeblock

```
var point = 
feature.getGeometry().getClosestPoint(evt.mapBrowserEvent.coordinate);

console.log(feature.getGeometry().intersectsCoordinate(point));
```

console always logs `false`, this really wondering me, considering [intersectsCoordinate()'s defination](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.Geometry.html#intersectsCoordinate)  `point` shall belong to `Feature` right?

Comment: Returns true if this geometry includes the specified coordinate. If the coordinate is on the boundary of the geometry, returns false.